Schnorr batch verify random number generation method
Is there a specific way that you must generate the random numbers for batch verification with Schnorr signatures?
In BIP 340 it describes this method for generating each random number:
seed = SHA256(pk1..pku || m1..mu || sig1..sigu)
a = []
for (2..u) do |i|
    a[i] = ChaCha20(seed) <- not sure if this is right or how this works, but ChaCha20 is recommended
end

But if you haven't got easy access to ChaCha20, would it be perfectly fine to use SHA-256 with an index instead:
seed = SHA256(pk1..pku || m1..mu || sig1..sigu)
for (2..u) do |i|
  a[i] = SHA256(seed || i)
end

Similarly, does the order of the data matter when creating the seed for the hash function? All of the same input data is getting hashed, just in a different order:
seed = SHA256(m1..mu || sig1..sigu || pk1..pku)
for (2..u) do |i|
  a[i] = SHA256(seed || i)
end

Basically I'm wondering if you can generate these numbers in any way you like as long as they are random and based on a hash of all the input data.
